# Why don't any of my rspec or cucumber tests run locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, cucumber

I have inherited a rails app which has an extensive suite of rspec and cucumber tests, when I run these tests on a CI server such as Circle, I see the tests run (most pass, some fail).

The app connects to a back-office API & I see the code has mocked responses to various API calls, the app also uses elasticsearch.

When I run the test suite locally using bundle exec rspec - I immediacy see a whole bunch of "Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest" errors from RSpec and failed to connect to those backoffice API's which I mentioned, however none of these failures occur on the CI server (yes, I have tried starting ES locally, same issue)

What am I doing wrong here? How can I run my tests locally to mirror what the CI server is doing to get them to run?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Can you post some of the console output? That's pretty much where I start troubleshooting and kind of hard to troubleshoot someone else's issue with no output.

Comment: My first guess is that your local Elasticsearch doesn't have the index that the tests use. Check the Circle configuration for any setup steps that are executed before the actual tests. This might give you an idea how to resolve the issue.